# Reading from a binary file

Tags: c++

I am trying to count the no of zeroes and ones from a binary file. The problem is, I am getting  correct no. of zeroes but ones are coming out to be equal to no. of zeroes.
What I am doing is reading the file char by char . Since there can be max 256 chars I am storing the results in a temporary array for both zeroes and ones, and retrieve from there if a character occurs again.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void func(int* a1 ,int* a2)
{
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        if( (i & 1) ==1 )
        {
            a1[i]+=1;
        }
        else if( (i & 1) ==0 )
        {
            a2[i]+=1;   
        }
        i>>1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int zero[256];
    int one[256];
    int tzero[256];
    int tone[256];
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        zero[i]=0;
        one[i]=0;
        tzero[i]=0;
        tone[i]=0;
    }
    func(tone,tzero);
    FILE* input;
    FILE* output;
    output=fopen("ascii.txt","w");
    input=fopen("one.bin","r");
    int c;
    while((c=fgetc(input))!=EOF)
    {
        fprintf(output,"%d\n",c);
        zero[c]+=tzero[c];
        one[c]+=tone[c];
    }
    int zeroes=0;
    int ones=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=255;i++)
    {
        zeroes+=zero[i];
        ones+=one[i];
    }
    cout<<"zeroes:"<<zeroes<<endl;
    cout<<"ones:"<<ones<<endl;
    fclose(input);

    fclose(output);

}
```

Comment: The second sentence of your question suggests that you don't have any problem at all.

Comment: What values do you expect `c` to take?

Comment: *"no of ones are coming out to be equal to no. of ones"*    What the heck are you talking about??

Comment: Why is this code so freaking complicated? It's a very simple problem! You don't even need to count zeros and ones separately; `ones = (file_size_in_bytes * 8) - zeros`. And why are there huge arrays? Aside from file handles, you need exactly two variables: a count and a temporary to hold the byte you just read.

Comment: Also, overusing "no" as "number" like that, really makes me want to just skip this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop that counts zeros and ones destroys the value of `c` by doing

```
c >>= 1;
```

After all eight shifts are complete, `c` is always zero, so the following code increments wrong counts:

```
// The value of c is always zero
tzero[c]=z;
tone[c]=o;
one[c]+=tzero[c];
zero[c]+=tzero[c];
```

You should save the value of `c` before the bit-counting loop, and restore it after the loop is over.

Better yet, compute the values of `tzero[]` and `tone[]` upfront, without waiting for them to occur in the file. This would make the body of your main loop very short and clean:

```
while((c=fgetc(input))!=EOF) {
    one[c] += tzero[c];
    zero[c] += tzero[c];
}
```

Comment: @user2733715 Could you edit the question with the code updates?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to bitwise count `1` and `0` bits in a file, you can simplify things greatly by using C++ file streams and not using lookup tables:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::ifstream fpInput("Input.txt");
  unsigned unOnes = 0;
  unsigned unZeros = 0;
  char chTemp;

  chTemp = fpInput.get();
  while (fpInput.good())
  {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
      if (chTemp & 0x1<<i) unOnes++;
      else unZeros++;
    }

    chTemp = fpInput.get();
  }

  fpInput.close();

  std::cout << "Found " << unOnes << " ones." << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Found " << unZeros << " zeros." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

A good compiler should expand the middle loop out if you pass it the right optimisation flags.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl..the file size can be huge ...therefore cant avoid look up tables would avoid recomputations.

Comment: @Anshul If speed is your concern, then I would suggest (firstly for clarity) replacing the C read file commands with C++ read file command and loading the contents of the file into a buffer.  Your current method of reading a file character by character can be slow.

Comment: @Anshul For 256 bytes of random data, I measured the execution time for 1000 executions of both programs (with a few minor tweaks to your program to make it work).  Your program took 1.7 seconds and mine took 1.8 seconds, this is very comparable especially considering I didn't have optimisation in mind when I wrote mine.  The added advantage of my program is I can give it a 10GB file and it will still run, yours requires further tweaking and if you intend to store the entire file contents in memory your program may not run.  Anyway... focus on writing easy to read code, optimise latter.

Comment: Thanks for the advises. But can u pls explain why wont my program run for a 10GB file?

Comment: @Anshul Your program requires loading the whole file into memory. With your current implementation you are using memory on the stack (http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/) which has a finite limit.  You could rewrite your program to use the heap, but I would suggest cutting your file into manageable chunks (this can be done by using `fpInput.read(buffer, buffer_size)`, or the C equivalent). You can process the buffer using either an un-optimised method like in my program or a lookup table as is in your program, either way you have some tweaking to do. Good Luck.